# Laravel tap into moment before query execution

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, scopes

I am using Laravel scopes to limit what the end user can see based on some provided input, however with my current use-case this is no longer acceptable.

Before applying additional queries, I would like to see what Eloquent method is being called, or at least see whether the ending SQL is performing a `SELECT`, `INSERT` or whatever before it is actually executed.

I can see that the `Model` is loading scopes within a constructor, which leads me to the conclusion that the actual query which would be executed without scopes is somewhere further down the line, however I can't seem to find it.

Is there some point where I can insert scopes (or similar equivalent) to the point right before the actual query is executed?

EDIT: even more confusing is the fact that `all()` method doesn't go inside Eloquent Builder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to do is not possible. Scopes are loaded and applied pretty early (before any Eloquent event is fired) upon model instantiation.

I had 2 ideas: one in this post, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052784/laravel-conditionally-add-global-scopes-after-method-boot); none of which worked. In the latter you can see what was the use case I needed, and how I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could throw an error, like this:

```
throw new Exception()
```

And then use the debug html output. It should have a tab, that shows the last queries. Not the most beautiful idea, but maybe it works.