# Laravel conditionally add global scopes after method boot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, scopes

Is it possible to add a global scope after the model has already passed the constructor?

I would like to catch an event (for example `creating`) and attach a global scope only if the model is creating.

So far I've done:

```
Event::listen('eloquent.creating*', function ($event, $model) {
    /**
     * @var Model $eloquentModel
     */
    $eloquentModel = $model[0];
    $eloquentModel->addGlobalScope(new AuthorizationScope($event));
});
```

The scope constructor is called, but the `apply` method from it is never fired because the model at that point already obviously passed the part where it fires the scopes. How could I manually fire it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? If I have a concrete use case I might think another way to do that.

Comment: I have a package to assemble queries based on some input. I am using these inside a scope to limit the output of the query. I would like the same to function on creating/updating/deleting.

Comment: It says in the docs that you need to enable the model events on the model class first to get model events. Did you do that? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events

Comment: Laravel fires these events independently of whether they are enabled or not. "Enabling" just enables you to redirect that event to your event class of choice. This part does work, I am catching events flawlessly. I actually found an alternative, will post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr; It is not possible. At the time when the Eloquent events are firing scopes are already loaded and applied.

Use case: I wanted to add additional scopes on model create/edit/delete to be able to do some sort of dynamic authorization, however this is not valid because Laravel uses Eloquent query builder for doing DB `SELECT`. For everything else, such as inserts or deletes, a different query is formed and is not connected to a given query builder, so even if you could tap into it, it makes no sense to do it as it would form a separate query for create/edit/delete actions anyways.

What I ended up doing was reusing the logic which I used within scopes, but instead of limiting the query initially (what scopes do), I would do my checks within event listener and return `true`/`false` depending on that check.

For this concrete example, returning `false` upon catching `eloquent.creating` event would mean that the model will not be created, which is exactly what I needed.

For any more details, feel free to check [authorization package for microservices](https://github.com/asseco-voice/laravel-json-authorization) I developed using this approach.